# During Ubuntu installation, Mouse doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, 16.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 from a USB drive (Using Rufus UEFI)

Sadly My Bluetooth Mouse, Logitech MX master doesn't work during the installation,
It's stuck on the upper left corner of the screen and only blinks during movement.

Any Ideas?

Comment: you have provided very little details,you should  tells where does it gets stuck,example on a live session (Try Ubuntu) or when the installation is going on and stuffs like that

Comment: First screen of the installation (Install, or try ubuntu). Sadly you are right, I don't have a lot of details because there are none. Plugged the USB, started by choosing in Boot option the boot drive, installation screen is up -> Mouse not responding as it should. Also not a lot of inromation (if any) over the internet

Comment: if the keyboard is working,why don't you install via cli?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is a mouse problem. You should check if your touchpad or touchscreen is dry and clean.

When you can see your mouse, the mouse DOES work.

Did you install other system on your computer? You should try with it.

Comment: The mouse doesn't work on ubuntu. It works perfect on Windows 10